# How can I change the main font of my Tufte-book style

Tags: fonts, tufte, books

I try to change my main font style in a Tufte book document class. Documentation say that it's possible by using the `nofonts` class option but nothing works. I tried the `\setmainfont` function, and other tricky solutions, without result. Here are my packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt, justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
  \graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, euscript}
\usepackage{mathabx, mathrsfs, mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\lstset{language=C}
```

Thanks for your help.

MWE:

Here is a minimal code of what I'm trying to do, remember that **I just want to change the text fond of my document**.

```
\documentclass[nofonts, justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathabx, mathrsfs, mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

%-----------For test-----------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
%------------------------------------------------------

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\lstset{language=C}

%=======================================================
%                       COLORS
%=======================================================
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

%=======================================================
%                  TITLES OPTIONS
%=======================================================
\titleformat*{\section}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{*2}{*2}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection\alph{subsubsection}}


\title{Test - tex.stackexchange.com}
\author[The Author]{The author}


%=======================================================
%                        MACROS
%=======================================================
\newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}
\newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}

\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al}.}
\newcommand{\ie}{\textbf{\textit{i}.\textit{e}. }}
\newcommand{\eg}{\textbf{\textit{e}.\textit{g}. }}
\newcommand{\cfr}{\textit{cfr}. }

\geometry{
  left=15mm,
  textwidth=140mm,
  headsep=10mm,
  headheight = 0mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,
  marginparwidth=50mm,
  bottom = 1.5cm, 
  top = 1.7cm
}

%=======================================================
%                    HEADER/FOOTER
%=======================================================
\pagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{The Author}
\lhead{TEST - tex.stackexchange.com}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
}

%=======================================================
%                      DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \fontfamily{pag}
    \begin{center}
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[draft]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \colorbox{grey}{
        \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
            \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
                \vspace{0.2cm}
                \begin{center}
                \fontsize{13pt}{0pt}\selectfont
                \text{TEST - tex.stackexchange.com}\\
                \fontsize{50pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries
                \vspace{0.3cm}\underline{Base project}\end{center} {\Huge2019}
                \vspace{0.7cm}
            }
        }
    }

    \vfill
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author name and informations
    %------------------------------------------------

    \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
        \raggedleft
        \large
        {\Large Author}\\[4pt]
        University\\
        \hfill\rule{0.2\linewidth}{1pt}
    }

\end{titlepage}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\section{Chapter 1:}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\begin{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You are already loading a bunch of font packages. Are you sure you need all those packages you have listed?

Comment: Yes most of them but I admit that I rather complete my package list as I write than to try to group them together. I'd already delete fontawesome, babel and euscript.

Comment: It's also questionable whether you should use `geometry` with `tufte`, whether you need `enumitem` and `enumerate`, whether you really want to use `mdframed` if you are already using `tcolorbox`, whether you need `lipsum` for a production document etc. It will help us help you if you could make your code example a MWE (minimal compilable working example).

Comment: @TeXnician, you will find it in answers below.

Comment: Next time, please use the edit button of your post. Did you try removing `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}` and then loading a package changing the font? That should work as expected (btw. you should not have a `\fontfamily{pag}` without `\selectfont` and maybe remove it to see changes made by font packages)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code was, that you were overriding any font settings in the preamble by explicitly selecting fonts with commands like `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}`.

After removing all the explicit font selections  <s>and several other things that dindn't spark joy</s> from your code you can now use a font of your choosing. I tried the [Linux Libertine and Biolinum Fonts](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine) with `\usepackage{libertine}`:

```
\documentclass[nobib,nofonts,justified]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}


\usepackage{libertine} % <-- Here



%-----------For test-----------------------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
%------------------------------------------------------
%                  TITLES OPTIONS
%=======================================================
\titleformat*{\section}{\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{*2}{*2}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection\alph{subsubsection}}


\title{Test - tex.stackexchange.com}
\author[The Author]{The author}


%=======================================================
%                      DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[draft]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \colorbox{gray}{
        \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
            \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
                \vspace{0.2cm}
                \begin{center}
                \fontsize{13pt}{0pt}\selectfont
                TEST - tex.stackexchange.com\\
                \fontsize{50pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries
                \vspace{0.3cm}\underline{Base project}\end{center} {\Huge2019}
                \vspace{0.7cm}
            }
        }
    }

    \vfill

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author name and informations
    %------------------------------------------------

    \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
        \raggedleft
        \large
        {\Large Author}\\[4pt]
        University\\
        \hfill\rule{0.2\linewidth}{1pt}
    }

\end{titlepage}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\section{Chapter 1:}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\begin{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{marginfigure}
\end{document}
```

`pdffonts` shows, that no other fonts were loaded:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
QFROIV+LinLibertineMT                Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      13  0
GYBFUK+LinLibertineT                 Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      14  0
AWSGUC+LinLibertineTB                Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      15  0
GYBFUK+LinLibertineT                 Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      21  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to this group...

You didn't mention the font name what you want to change. By using the code `\usepackage{palatino,mathpazo}` able to change the main font to Palatino

Comment: I've also try this solution, it doesn't work either..

Comment: @GuilianDeflandre Then, confirm what type of TeX engine you are using, e.g., MikTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, etc.

Comment: @MadyYuvi You should not recommend using `palatino` (see l2tabu for an explanation). And MikTeX is no TeX engine but a TeX distribution.

Comment: @MadyYuvi pdfLaTex on OverLeaf mainly.